# Position of Game AI in world

Tags: animation, artificial-intelligence

I have a question about controlling position of AI character in games.

in most games animations of player are inplace so position of character is in our hands.

but when look at AI animations, they are not in place. for example when an ai moves forward his animation moves one step in localspace. if we want to loop
this animation, after one step character go back to first place.
we need ai moves forward in the world.

my question is : how to update position of ai character in world space?

you can find more information here. http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/RootMotion.html

how unreal engine use movement of root bone to move it's own actor in the world.

thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but some things are not clear. Are you talking about AI character's positioning in relation to the game world or it's animation? Are you saying the character is going back to it's starting position when it was supposed to move forward? (@"if we want to loop this animation, after one step character go back to first place. we need ai moves forward in the world.") Also, updating it's position will depend on how the positioning is done, so that needs clarification too. (@"my question is : how to update position of ai character in world space?")

Comment: i mean how to update position of ai in world. assume we have an animation that jump 1 meter forward. this 1 meter is in local space.if i move ai forward, movement will be twice and ugly. because animation moves in localspace and i move ai in worldspace. rootbone of character is child of ai character. maybe by playing this animation in front of a wall ai go throw wall and i want to keep it out of wall each frame.

Answer (score 1):

Characters' animations shouldn't define how their position changes, just their movements, so it doesn't move in the local space.
For example, in a walking animation the character moves its legs, maybe its arms, but it doesn't move forward. This makes looping and concatenating animations much easier.

Comment: yes, this would be perfect. but if you resource games you see a lot of animations that are not 'inplace'. movements can be more realistic when designed in apps like maya and 3dmax because of motion capture and simulating this movements in games with rigidbody and forces is hard and result not good enough. some movements are not linear and make a path like a curve.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it the exact same as what your character would do?

Note that the animation itself has nothing to do with "moving" in the game world. What's important is that the engine synchronizes translation of the model and playing of the animation so it looks as if the "walk" animation moved the character forward.

The animation must contain meta-data that tells the engine how much translation/velocity changes are produced or this must be hard-coded in the engine for specifically named animations and all animators must match their animations to the translations the engine will produce.